# Java if statement always returns true

Tags: java, if-statement, null

I am trying to validate some input from a Swing form by checking for null values. However the checkFirstName method is always returning true. So for example if i leave the firstname blank on the form it will return true even though the field is null.

Here is my two methods, the first one is fired when the user clicks the save button.

```
public void saveNewCustomer() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

        boolean dbOK = false;//boolean to check if data input is not null

        System.out.println(dbOK);
        String firstName = txtNCustomerFirstName.getText();
        String lastName = txtNCustomerLastName.getText();

        if (checkFirstName(firstName)) {
            dbOK = true;
        } else {
            lblNCustFirstNameError.setText("First Name Must be Entered");
            dbOK = false;
        }
        System.out.println(dbOK);

        if (dbOK) {
            dbConnector.insertSignup(firstName, lastName);
            System.out.println("Success");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }

    public boolean checkFirstName(String firstName) {
        boolean allOK = false;
        System.out.println(allOK);

        if (firstName != null) {
            allOK = true;
        } else {
            allOK = false;
        }
        return allOK;
    }
```

Have i done something wrong cause this to me should be return false cause the firstname field is null.

Comment: Is `firstname` really `null` or is it just empty? I would recommend to use the `StringUtils` class from Apache commons for that: http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html

Comment: Have you tried `!firstName.isEmpty()`? Debugger should be your best friend...

Comment: You can shorten your code. Instead `boolean flag=false; if (contidion){flag=true;} else {flag=false;} return flag;` use `return condition;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So for example if i leave the firstname blank on the form

You are just checking for `null`, you need to do empty `("")` String check also.

It should be something like:

```
if (firstName != null && !"".equals(firstName.trim()) {
```

Comment: Should also trim it in case there's a blank character (after the null check, of course).

Answer (score 3):

The `String` will never be null, the `String` will be empty. Check `firstName.isEmpty()`. Still I suggest you keep the check for null too:

```
public boolean checkFirstName(String firstName) {
    boolean allOK = false;
    System.out.println(allOK);

    if (firstName != null && !firstName.isEmpty()) {
        allOK = true;
    } else {
        allOK = false;
    }
    return allOK;
}
```

EDIT: as pointed out by Windle you probably would like to check if the String has at least one non-whitespace:

```
if (firstName != null && !firstName.trim().isEmpty())
```

Also you may perform more complex verification - for instance if you want to make sure there are no whitespaces in the username after you trim it.

Comment: @Nambari thank you. Too many languages... I get confused from time to time :) Fixed.

Comment: @Nambari http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty%28%29

Comment: @predi thank you too. I knew it that I can't be **that** confused :)

Comment: +1 But is `!firstName.isEmpty()` really what we want here? Since OP is checking a name wouldn't `!firstName.trim().isEmpty()` be closer to the right thing? Sure you could do more complex verification, but at least that catches strings of whitespace too.  Better yet, changing `txtNCustomerFirstName.getText()` to `txtNCustomerFirstName.getText().trim()` fixes it in the very beginning.

Answer (score 0):

The `txtNCustomerFirstName.getText` method is returning an empty string. You might change your `checkFirstName` method's if statement to check for an empty string:

```
if (firstName != null && !firstName.isEmpty()) {
```

If you don't have Java 6+, you can use `firstName.length() > 0` instead of `isEmpty`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, the getText() method you're calling in the saveNewCustomer() will return an empty string rather than null.

Answer (score 0):

> So for example if i leave the firstname blank on the form it will
>   return true even though the field is null.

This is where your reasoning is wrong. When you leave a text field blank, `getText()` returns **an empty string** i.e. `""` which is *not null*. You should check for emptiness instead of `null`.

```
if (!firstName.isEmpty()) { ... }
```

If `firstName` may also be `null` (e.g. when it comes from another source), you should check that beforehand:

```
if (firstName != null && !firstName.isEmpty()) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

As other answers have suggested do a null check with an empty string check. I'd say trim the leading and trailing whitespaces also before doing an empty check because in reality you want to avoid such situation.

```
if (firstName != null && !firstName.trim().isEmpty()) { ... }
```